# different methods for image thresholding for creating binary images

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have two methods here that seem to give the same result for creating a binary image, but I am not sure if they are different in any ways or when one is used over the other? Any thoughts? Thanks.

```
retval, sxbinary = cv2.threshold(abssx, 20, 100, cv2.THRESH_BINARY) 

sxbinary = np.zeros_like(abssx)
sxbinary[(abssx >= 20) & (abssx <= 100)] = 1
```

Comment: You need to look up the documentation. But it is highly likely that cv2.threshold with THRESH_BINARY is a relatively stupid function that just sets all pixels within certain limits.

Comment: I am  not looking to understand cv2.threshold, but rather the difference between the two methods I have stated above that yield the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct answer to my question:

problem is with `cv2.threshold()` doesn't actually take a lower an upper threshold, just a lower threshold and "max" value, which will be assigned to all pixels that are above the lower threshold.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#threshold) of the `cv2.threshold()` method then you may find that the params are defined as:

```
cv2.threshold(src, thresh, maxval, type[, dst]) → retval, dst
```

> src – input array (single-channel, 8-bit or 32-bit floating point).
>
> dst – output array of the same size and type as src.
>
> thresh –threshold value.
>
> maxval – maximum value to use with the THRESH_BINARY and THRESH_BINARY_INV thresholding types.
>
> type – thresholding type

So the third param you pass with `100` as value is actally the intensity value to used for pixels which are above the given threshold `20`, writing the same in numpy format would look something like:

```
sxbinary[(abssx >= 20)] = 100
```

However if you want to segment the pixels in a given range then you need to look at the [`cv2.inRange()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#inrange) method

Comment: I am  not looking to understand cv2.threshold, but rather the difference between the two methods I have stated above that yield the same result.